# How to display something after an option from a drop down list has been selected using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create an online store and I would like for when someone selects something from the first drop down list e.g. (Meat Lovers pizza) I want it to display (Enjoy some delicious meat pizza) at the bottom of that drop down list and take away the select something option after that.

My code is in the following code snippet:

```js
/* GLOBAL VARIABLES */
    
    var theList;
    var prices;
    var meat;
    var select;
    
    window.onload = function () {
      //var option = document.createElement ("option"); 

      //option.textContent= theList;
      //productList.appendChild (option);
    //}
    
    $('#theList').on('change', function () {
        $("#meat").css('display', (this.value == '1') ? 'block' : 'none');
    });
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>
     <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="assignment2.css">
      <H1> ASSIGNMENT 2- DOM Scripting - Pizza and Wings</H1>
     </head
     <body>
      <div id="selection"><H4>PRODUCT SELECTION</H4>
       
       Whats your fancy? <select id ="theList" name="theList">
                
                <option id="select" value="0">Select product here</option>
                            <option id="meat" value="meat">Meat Lovers Pizza</option>    
                            <option id="margaritta" value="margaritta">Margaritta</option>
                            <option id="" value="2">Pepparoni</option>
                            <option id="" value="3">Plain cheese</option>
                       </select>
                        
                <div style='display:none;' id='meat'>Meat
        <br/>&nbsp;
        <input type='text' class='text' name='meat' value size='20' />
        <br/>
    </div>
      
      
     <div><h4>YOUR CHOICES</h4>
      <div>Which one would you like?  <div class="prices">
                        <input type="radio" id="price1" name="price" value="1"> $9.95 -small(6 slices)<br>
                        <input type="radio" id="price2" name="price" value="2">$12.95 -medium(8 slices)<br>
                        <input type="radio" id="price3" name="price" value="3">$15.95 -large(10 slices)<br>
                   <input type="radio" id="price4" name="price" value="4">$19.95 -party size(16 slices)<br></div>
      </div>
      
      
      
      
     <div> Any extras?  <div> <input type="radio" id="price1" name="price" value="1"> thin crust $0.49<br>
          <input type="radio" id="price2" name="price" value="2">whole wheat $0.95<br>
      <input type="radio" id="price3" name="price" value="3">extra cheese $1.49<br></div></div>
      
      How many? <input id="amount" type="text"><br>  <div class="button">
                <input type="button" class="btn" id="add" value="ADD TO ORDER">
          <input type="button" class="btn" id="remove" value="REMOVE LAST ITEM">
      <br>
            </div> 
                
      <h4> ORDER STATUS </h4>
      ITEMS: <input id="items" type="text">
            TOTAL: <input id="credits" type="text"> <input type="button" class="btn" id="now" value="ORDER NOW"> <input type="button" class="btn" id="cancel" value="CANCEL">
            
      
      
      </div>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="assignment2.js"></script>           
     </body>
     
     </html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What are the steps to reproduce? Expected behavior? Actual behavior? Error message? Please don't just post code and expect others to parse and debug it in their head. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Look up how the javascript functions for onChange and selectedIndex work.  That will give you all the answers you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two elements currently with an ID of 'meat' and as ID's have to be unique so it will find the first one which is the option in the select list. I changed this to be 'meat-lover', and made the option values consistent.

For hiding the 'select product' option, I used a similar comparison to check if they selected anything other than that option and hid it if so.

```
$("#select").css('display', (this.value == '0') ? 'block' : 'none');
```

A couple of other things to note, the head tag is missing a closing angle brace and jQuery isn't currently defined on the code samples you provided but that might just be you creating the test case.

Here is a demo I put together of it in action: http://codepen.io/jjclane/pen/rOoyGY

Comment: Thank you but the code doesn't seem to work anywhere else but on codepen

Comment: I've taken your code from the post and edited it, obviously removing the html, head and body tags as they don't work on codepen, but other than that is should be the same?

Comment: I add them back and tried to test it but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Are you getting any console errors? Is the javascript running?

Comment: Yes,  

$('#theList').on('change', function () {

Comment: Can you help me with something else Jordan?

Comment: Yeah, what do you need?